# Running Kubernetes Example on CoreOS, Part 1 not work

Tags: docker, coreos, kubernetes

I'm trying to eval [Kubernetes](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes). I interesting to mount kubernetes on CoreOS cluster, and official documentation not have much, only have two references to blog of CoreOS; I'm currently using guide to [running kubernetes example on CoreOS part 1](https://coreos.com/blog/running-kubernetes-example-on-CoreOS-part-1/).

**My apiserver.service:**

```
[Unit]
ConditionFileIsExecutable=/opt/kubernetes/bin/apiserver
Description=Kubernetes API Server
[Unit]
ConditionFileIsExecutable=/opt/kubernetes/bin/controller-manager
Description=Kubernetes Controller Manager
Documentation=https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/kubernetes/bin/controller-manager \
--etcd_servers=http://127.0.0.1:4001 \
--master=127.0.0.1:8080 \
--logtostderr=true
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=1

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Documentation=https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/kubernetes/bin/apiserver \
--address=127.0.0.1 \
--port=8080 \
--etcd_servers=http://127.0.0.1:4001 \
--machines=127.0.0.1 \
--logtostderr=true
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=1

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**My controller-manager.service:**

```
[Unit]
ConditionFileIsExecutable=/opt/kubernetes/bin/controller-manager
Description=Kubernetes Controller Manager
Documentation=https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/kubernetes/bin/controller-manager \
--etcd_servers=http://127.0.0.1:4001 \
--master=127.0.0.1:8080 \
--logtostderr=true
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=1

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**My kubelet.service:**

```
[Unit]
ConditionFileIsExecutable=/opt/kubernetes/bin/kubelet
Description=Kubernetes Kubelet
Documentation=https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/kubernetes/bin/kubelet \
--address=127.0.0.1 \
--port=10250 \
--hostname_override=127.0.0.1 \
--etcd_servers=http://127.0.0.1:4001 \
--logtostderr=true
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=1

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**My proxy.service**

```
[Unit]
ConditionFileIsExecutable=/opt/kubernetes/bin/proxy
Description=Kubernetes Proxy
Documentation=https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/kubernetes/bin/proxy --etcd_servers=http://127.0.0.1:4001 --logtostderr=true
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=1

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The problem arises when I create a Kubernetes pod redis.

**When I execute command:**

```
/opt/kubernetes/bin/kubecfg -h http://127.0.0.1:8080 -c kubernetes-coreos/pods/redis.json create /pods
```

**the error outputs after a long time waiting:**

```
{Kind:"", ID:"", CreationTimestamp:"", SelfLink:"", ResourceVersion:0x0}, Status:"failure", Details:"failed to find fit for api.Pod{JSONBase:api.JSONBase{Kind:\"\", ID:\"redis\", CreationTimestamp:\"\", SelfLink:\"\", ResourceVersion:0x0}, Labels:map[string]string{\"name\":\"redis\"}, DesiredState:api.PodState{Manifest:api.ContainerManifest{Version:\"v1beta1\", ID:\"redis\", Volumes:[]api.Volume(nil), Containers:[]api.Container{api.Container{Name:\"redis\", Image:\"registry.vc.datys.cu:5000/redis\", Command:[]string(nil), WorkingDir:\"\", Ports:[]api.Port{api.Port{Name:\"\", HostPort:6379, ContainerPort:6379, Protocol:\"\", HostIP:\"\"}}, Env:[]api.EnvVar(nil), Memory:0, CPU:0, VolumeMounts:[]api.VolumeMount(nil), LivenessProbe:api.LivenessProbe{Enabled:false, Type:\"\", HTTPGet:api.HTTPGetProbe{Path:\"\", Port:\"\", Host:\"\"}, InitialDelaySeconds:0}}}}, Status:\"\", Host:\"\", HostIP:\"\", Info:api.PodInfo(nil)}, CurrentState:api.PodState{Manifest:api.ContainerManifest{Version:\"\", ID:\"\", Volumes:[]api.Volume(nil), Containers:[]api.Container(nil)}, Status:\"\", Host:\"\", HostIP:\"\", Info:api.PodInfo(nil)}}", Code:500}
```

NOTE: When I execute: `sudo systemctl status proxy` return:

```
● proxy.service - Kubernetes Proxy
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/proxy.service; disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2014-08-08 14:21:36 UTC; 8s ago
     Docs: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes
 Main PID: 1036 (proxy)
   CGroup: /system.slice/proxy.service
           └─1036 /opt/kubernetes/bin/proxy --etcd_servers=http://127.0.0.1:4001 --logtostderr=true

Aug 08 14:21:42 core-01 proxy[1036]: I0808 14:21:42.074694 01036 logs.go:38] etcd DEBUG: [recv.success. http://127.0.0.1:4001/v2/keys/registry/ser...rted=true]
Aug 08 14:21:42 core-01 proxy[1036]: E0808 14:21:42.074763 01036 etcd.go:115] Failed to get the key registry/services: 100: Key not found (/registry) [57]
Aug 08 14:21:42 core-01 proxy[1036]: E0808 14:21:42.074791 01036 etcd.go:75] Failed to get any services: 100: Key not found (/registry) [57]
Aug 08 14:21:44 core-01 proxy[1036]: I0808 14:21:44.075337 01036 logs.go:38] etcd DEBUG: get [registry/services/specs http://127.0.0.1:4001] [%!s(MISSING)]
Aug 08 14:21:44 core-01 proxy[1036]: I0808 14:21:44.075501 01036 logs.go:38] etcd DEBUG: [Connecting to etcd: attempt 1 for keys/registry/services...rted=true]
Aug 08 14:21:44 core-01 proxy[1036]: I0808 14:21:44.075528 01036 logs.go:38] etcd DEBUG: [send.request.to  http://127.0.0.1:4001/v2/keys/registry/...thod  GET]
Aug 08 14:21:44 core-01 proxy[1036]: I0808 14:21:44.078524 01036 logs.go:38] etcd DEBUG: [recv.response.from http://127.0.0.1:4001/v2/keys/registr...rted=true]
Aug 08 14:21:44 core-01 proxy[1036]: I0808 14:21:44.078824 01036 logs.go:38] etcd DEBUG: [recv.success. http://127.0.0.1:4001/v2/keys/registry/ser...rted=true]
Aug 08 14:21:44 core-01 proxy[1036]: E0808 14:21:44.078897 01036 etcd.go:115] Failed to get the key registry/services: 100: Key not found (/registry) [57]
Aug 08 14:21:44 core-01 proxy[1036]: E0808 14:21:44.078925 01036 etcd.go:75] Failed to get any services: 100: Key not found (/registry) [57]
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

And when execute: `/opt/kubernetes/bin/kubecfg -h http://127.0.0.1:8080 list /pods` return:

```
Name                Image(s)                          Host                Labels
----------          ----------                        ----------          ----------
redis               dockerfile/redis   127.0.0.1/          name=redis
```

What's the problem? I appreciate any idea or collaboration.

**EDIT 1:**

**My redis.json:**

```
{
  "id": "redis",
  "desiredState": {
    "manifest": {
      "version": "v1beta1",
      "id": "redis",
      "containers": [{
        "name": "redis",
        "image": "registry.vc.datys.cu:5000/redis",
        "ports": [{
          "containerPort": 6379,
          "hostPort": 6379
        }]
      }]
    }
  },
  "labels": {
    "name": "redis"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The errors you are seeing in your log is that the pod you are trying to create has a port conflict with the Kubernetes API server. Both are trying to use port 8080. Fix this issue by changing the pod to run on another port.

You'll have to clean things up first. So remove the redis pod using kubecfg command. Update the pod.json file, and try again.

Also please follow the quickstart guide found at the https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-coreos. Kubernetes is a fast moving project, so that blog will become out of date fairly quickly.